# Matched values between 2 arrays must set the option HTML, to disabled

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

I'm new to javascript. I have 2 arrays, how can I match them and return an  HTML. If there are values matched in two arrays, the select option is disabled.
for example:

```
var array1 = ["8:00AM", "9:00AM", "10:00AM","11:00AM",]
var array2 = ["11:00AM", "11:00AM", "3:00PM"]

array1.map((el, i) => <option key={i} disabled ={
el.includes(array2) ? true: false
}>{el}</option>))
```

what I would like to happen is if there are values matched between the 2 arrays, in this case "11:00AM", it would return:

```
<option> 8:00AM</option>
<option> 9:00AM</option>
<option> 10:00AM</option>
<option disabled = {true} > 11:00AM</option>
<option> 12:00PM</option>
```

something like this. Is this possible with my current method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)'s syntax would be

```
arr.includes(valueToFind[, fromIndex])
```

Also, you can use [Template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) as follows:

```js
var array1 = ["8:00AM", "9:00AM", "10:00AM", "11:00AM", ]
var array2 = ["11:00AM", "11:00AM", "3:00PM"]

const element = document.querySelector('select');
element.innerHTML = array1.map((el, i) =>
  `<option key=${i} ${array2.includes(el) ? 'disabled': ''}>${el}</option>`
).join('');
```

```html
<select>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can use `indexOf` and check value exist or not, Try this below Code

```
array1.map((el, i) => <option key={i} disabled={
    array2.indexOf(el) > -1 ? true : false
}>{el}</option>)
```